# Need help in deciding the layout of an interaction

Tags: forms, interaction-design, layout, textbox

I am currently designing a system where doctor needs to input a reason for every case(patient history). My current concern is the placement of the reason box.

First time there will not be any data in the table hence I placed the reason box on the top as once user adds reason it gets updated accordingly in table.[image: initial]

Second time, User will be seeing the details in the table. 
[image: placement of reason box]

My concern is if I have to edit the details in the table is it okay to populate the data in the reason box above (as shown in image 1). Will he be confused or Should I move the reason box below the table(as shown in second image) Is there any better way to do this.

PS: This interaction is similar to the stack exchange for adding a question.

Answer (score 1):

As your users are probably doctors or patients, they will not be so much concentrated onto the thing. So you need to bring their attention to where you want.

I would suggest, you give a popup, that comes up (containing whatever to edit and confirm or cancel buttons.) or a slide down layout (that contains the editable things).

Answer (score 1):

go with the second interaction. because as the doc opens the screen

- He sees the existing reports/ reason in many cases and showing them in the top is preferable as he can quickly view and edit the them as he needs.
- or if he is opening for the first time he creates his reason/report which is at the bottom which is no wrong because if you see any famous applications like facebook or instagram comment sections always **ADD** is at the bottom of the screen.

[image]
[image]

---

Anyways I suggest you to have a **market survey** or **user research** on the use cases of creation and viewing of the reports. though in both of those cases the 2nd option goes perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents will be to  keep the reason text field **below the table**, but  do make a small change in the table and  the heading of the field .

When the user sets up an application for a new patient, i.e someone with no history. The table should be present with a row that say "No Previous History"

And then,as you had mentioned, the text field can be placed below that empty table , as the user will most definitely skim over the text before adding a new entry giving a heads up that the user is going to add a new entry.

To add to this , the heading for the Text entry should reflect what action the user is taking, in case of adding a new entry it should read "Add Reason " and when in the case of Editing it should read "Edit Reason" , more appropriate wordings can be used.

So, i would vote for keeping the table first and the text field second.